# Git merge: like in 'Merge pull request #8 from githubUser/branch'

Tags: git, github

I am new to distributed git workflows and am wondering how I can achive a commit with the standard message like in the title. Also I want to see graphically the merge of the feature branch in `git log --graph` of the master.

My repo looks like:

```
*---* master
    \---*---*---*---* feature
```

How can this be done? If I do `git checkout master; git merge feature` I just linearly advance the master pointer and don't see that I merged a feature branch. Ideally I'd like to push this to a Github origin and want the merge to be seen.

To clarify my goal:

```
*---* master---------------------*---*---* master
    \---*---*---*---* feature---/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `--no-ff` flag in your merge command to have a merge commit even if a fast-forward merge would have been possible (like this is the case here).

Comment: @RomainValeri How does this look like when I `git push origin master`? Is the feature branch visible in `git log` but not in `git branch`? This is what I'd like to have.

Comment: If You push to the master, then You won't have any info about previous branches, you should use git merge for that :)

Comment: not have your branch displayed in `git branch`? You mean delete it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I push origin master and somewone clones the master. Do they see the merge message of the feature branch but don't have the branch locally?

Comment: @avermaet Oh, I get your question now. Yes, the coworker will see a merge commit but no they won't "have the branch locally", only the ones they explicitly want to get. If you didn't push your feature branch to remote, or they didn't recreate itlocal explicitly, no worries.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks now you got me, my first question was just not clear enough :-)

Comment: @avermaet Ironically enough, when one asks a question, often, the knowledge he asks for is also partly required to formulate the question with clarity in the first place :-)